# $(window).scroll(function() not working on firefox?

Tags: jquery, firefox

In order to load pages as facebook or twitter does at their sites, scrolling down, i have tried this with jquery:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
        //do something
    }
}
```

And i am having troubles with Firefox. Not with Chrome and either with Safari (IE not tested yet).

If i use an "alert('xx')" inside the IF, Firefox crashes and i have to restart it.

I am using the Mac version of Firefox but i guess that's not an important fact.

Anyone have any idea about what's happening here?
Thanks.

Comment: is it a typo that you missed the `);` at the end of the scroll function?

Comment: Does your code possibly contain typos? Because what you've pasted is missing the closing `)` and `;` for the `$(window).scroll();` call.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me that whenever the user scrolls, you manually set a scrolling position.

Comment: Nah, that was just a copy and past error.
I really dont know where was the problem but for some reason Firefox was giving me a one those sizes bad, with 1 pixels less.
So doing this worked well: if($(document).height() - $(window).height() <= $(window).scrollTop()+1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have the same problem: it works in chrome but not in firefox and IE. After debugging i found that there is a 1 px difference between $(document).height() - $(window).height() and $(window).scrollTop() in firefox but not in chrome. My working solution here:

```
    if  ($(window).scrollTop() + 1 >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()){

      //do something here

    }
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what i said on one of my replies to the first answer.

Comment: Yeah. That's what i said on my reply to the fist answer.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an really old article, but i was struggling with this today. I was trying to active an counter when it came into my viewport. It stopped working after i added some style to my style.css.

```
  html { 
    scroll-behaviour: smooth
  }
```

So, may this be in you favour, adding this will cause $(window).scroll function stop working on firefox and IE.

Comment: Should be "scroll-behavior"

Answer (score 2):

The `scroll` event is firing so many times that your Firefox browser is crashing. Instead of using `alert()`, use `console.log()`...

Here is a demo to show how many events are fired: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/tQmRU/

Comment: That was not the problem. I was not talking about using an alert() on scroll but just when it gets the bottom of the page. Only when it enters on that IF.

I finally discovered the reason. I dont know why Firefox 11 calculates with an error of 1pixel some of the sizes. So doing this would work: 
if($(document).height() - $(window).height() <= $(window).scrollTop()+1)....

Comment: I had same problem, he is right, it is the alert (for me at least)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem occurring because I had put a Firebug breakpoint inside the scroll handler, not an `alert()`.  I instead used a `console.log()` for debugging, and that did not cause crashing.