# cross browser mouse wheel, to scroll 100% browser height by one single wheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, mousewheel

Have some js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var winHeight = window.innerHeight ?
        function() {
            return window.innerHeight;
        } :
        function() {
            return document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        };
$('.first-block').height(winHeight);
$(window).scroll(function(){

var firstBlockHeight = winHeight();
var scrollTop= $('body').scrollTop();

if (scrollTop > 0 && scrollTop < firstBlockHeight/2 && $('body').hasClass('scrolled') === false) {
$("body")
  .animate({ scrollTop: firstBlockHeight+10 }, 600)
  .addClass('scrolled');

} else if (scrollTop==0) {
$("body")
.animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600)
.removeClass('scrolled');
}
 });
 });
```

which scrolls first block 100% height by single mouse wheel. This code dont work in firefox.. And there are bugs if play with scrolling.. Help please fix that and add cross browser support.
See please [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CroaToa/zgc4h8eo/).

Thanks.

Comment: please don't 2nd-guess the way i set my mouse up, i rather like my settings ...

Comment: @dandavis I'm sorry, I did not understand you at all..

Comment: have you seen this question already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471286/window-scrollfunction-not-working-on-firefox

Comment: @JaimeGomez thank for link, but I cant see there bug with cyclical scrolling.

Comment: @CroaToa I believe that dandavis was implying that changing the user's scrolling behavior is not the best for your UX.

Comment: I agree with him, but if designer want it, I need to do.. Users scrolling changes 1 single time, in top block)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use mouswheel.js and I do it! :)
may be useful for someone

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var winHeight = window.innerHeight ?
            function() {
                return window.innerHeight;
            } :
            function() {
                return document.documentElement.clientHeight;
            };
$('.first-block').height(winHeight);
var BlockHeight = $('.first-block').height();
$.browser = {};
$.browser.mozilla = /mozilla/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()) &&     !/webkit/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
if($.browser.mozilla)
{
 var ScrollType = 'html';
  }
else
   {
 var ScrollType = 'body';
  }
$('.first-block').mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
  if((delta<0) && ($(ScrollType).scrollTop()==0)) $(ScrollType).animate({ scrollTop: BlockHeight-    104 }, 600);
});

$(ScrollType).keydown(function(event){
 if((event.keyCode==40) && ($(ScrollType).scrollTop()==0)) $(ScrollType).animate({ scrollTop:  BlockHeight-104 }, 600);
})

});
```

thanks for me)